# Unable to install WebDriverAgent on real device using developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automation

I am able to install `WebDriverAgent` using my personal `apple id`, But when I am using Developer account I am getting an error on running

> xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme
>   WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=' test

my terminal is stuck at a point where it says

> "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[669:141632] Using singleton test manager
>   "

and later (~30-40 minutes)i get an error

Testing failed:

> WebDriverAgentRunner:   testRunner encountered an error (Encountered a
>   problem with the test runner after launch. (Underlying error: Lost
>   connection to DTServiceHub))

See Below Image

[image]